# Django SlugField pretty SEO URL

Tags: python, django

I want to create SEO friendly product URLS:-

Following is my url:-

```
url(r'^ad/(?P<slug>[-\w\d]+),(?P<pk>\d+)/$', (views.AdDetail.as_view()), name='item_detail'),
```

My views:-

```
class AdDetail(View):
    template_name = 'ads/ad_detail.html'

    def get(self, request, slug, pk, *args, **kwargs):
        ad = AdDetailAPI.get_ad(pk)
        return render(request, self.template_name, ctx)
```

My templates:-

```
<a href="{% url 'item_detail' slug=item.slug pk=item.id %}">
```

This is where the problem lies, it says `NoReverseMatch`

`Reverse for 'item_detail' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'pk': 47L, u'slug': ''}' not found. 2 pattern(s) tried: [u'ad/(?P<slug>[-\\w\\d]+),(?P<pk>\\d+)\\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$', 'ad/(?P<slug>[-\\w\\d]+),(?P<pk>\\d+)/$']`

**Where does the problem exactly lies?**

Also, when I browse to `/ad/abcd,46` or `/ad/pqr,46`, as expected it shows the content of object 46. But the browser url gets change to `/ad/pqr,46` from `/ad/abcd,46`. What I want is that the irrespective of whatever slugfield is typed into the browser address, the address bar should show the actual title slugfield assigned.

Comment: The slug for `47L` doesn't match (`'}`), looking at it though, the problem is probably to do with where you set the slug

Comment: This is how I slugify it, `slug=slugify(ad_title)`.

Comment: `slugify('foo\'}') == 'foo'` so for this particular entry, something didn't work correctly

Comment: Got it working. Was a mistake from my side. Thanks :)
Any idea about the second query? As in how do I redirect it back to the same url if the `slug` field is changed in the address bar.?

Comment: You should make a new question to ask about that really, but if it helps, stackoverflow just redirects you to the correct url (You can try it by deleting  some of the text from the slug to this question)

Comment: Which means same view is called twice, if slug field is not the same?

Comment: If you need further explanation I'd say ask a new question, but [yes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFIFC.png)